# Ajax POST request sending undefined to Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to send some data to be parsed. The script on the client side is the following:

```
function addURL(link) {
        console.log("Adding url...");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/shorturl/create",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({url:link}),
            success: function(data){
                $("#shortenedURL").html(data.shortenedURL);
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log("Ran into an error... " + err);
            }
        });
}
```

On my express app, on one of the routers, I've got:

```
router.post("/create", function(req, res){

console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.body.url);
var url = req.body.url; }
```

I get 'undefined', and then the 'Cannot get property 'url' of undefined'.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong...

Comment: are you sure that the url: link that you are sending has a value on the ajax?

Comment: what expressjs version you are using andpost your app.js code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

app.js:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```